# How to use findViewById in fragment and ArrayList cannot be applied - Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have had to change a class from it being classed as a activity to a fragment and I don't know how I would set this up now as it now says that it cannot resolve the method on my findViewById. Any extra code can be given if required. Thanks for helping.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle      savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.game_list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}
}
```

This is what is causing me trouble with the findViewById because it cannot resolve the method:

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.game_list);
```

And this is what is causing me problems on the ArrayList and apparently it is because LazyAdapter (android.app.Activity, ArrayList>) in LazyAdapter cannot be applied to (com.example.app.CustomizedListView, ArrayList>)

```
        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e5e5e5" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/game_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#e5e5e5"
    android:dividerHeight="6dp"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error is on method onCreate: view creation must go on method **onCreateView** instead.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Preparing user interface
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_list);
    // Do what you want...

    return v;
}
```

> ...is because LazyAdapter (android.app.Activity, ArrayList>) in
>   LazyAdapter cannot be applied to (com.example.app.CustomizedListView,
>   ArrayList>)

You got a clue to your problem. IMHO you have to change the way you are using LazyAdapter. I suggest you to: check if my code solved your problem with Fragment, then ask another question regarding ArrayList/LazyAdapter problem.

Comment: How would I place this within my code. Im getting muddled up here for some reason and my brain isn't working.

Comment: Take a pause of 10 mins, then return and do this: instead of creating ListView on method "onCreate", do it on "onCreateView" like I do in my code. Do you have your layout.xml in res/layout folder?

Comment: It is telling me your code for the ListView creation is not a statement.

Comment: @ThePoloDoc post your layout.xml code on your question, please.

Comment: Do you need any others now?

Comment: @ThePoloDoc i tried a little example by my own and it's ok. Sincerely i don't know where is your problem on Fragment. If you really don't need it, use a simple Activity just for a test: Fragments are a little complicated if you are new on Android.

Comment: Could you post the basic code you used so I could check it against mine?

Comment: @ThePoloDoc I can give you better things: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html (this is a link of an Android Guru) and an official Android page http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html . Read carefully, this will help you much more.

Comment: I know the majority of this as I have used fragments somewhat before. This is a rather confined error to my code which something like this will not help me with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use getActivity().findViewById(id), but only if you know that the fragment is indeed attached to an activity. If it's not, getActivity() will return null.

An alternative is to call findViewById on a View that is inside the fragment, e.g. the view that you return in onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

And you'd better

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_with_list, container, false);
findViewById(id)
```

This:

```
 getActivity().findViewById(id)
```

activity will be null before attached to activity.

Comment: like this? list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.game_list);